# How should $A^α$ be defined for real $α ∈ [0,∞)$ and $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ be arbitrary. I'm interested to know How should $A^{\alpha}$ be defined for real $\alpha\in [0,\infty)$? When $A$ is nonsingular, we can define $A^{\alpha}=\exp(\alpha \log(A))$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$ and $A^{\alpha}=A^{[\alpha]}.A^{\alpha-[\alpha]}$ ([.] denote the intiger part) for $\alpha \gt 1$. But what we can do about singular matrices?

Comment: What's your definition of $\log A$ if, say, $A$ has complex eigenvalues of absolute value greater than $1$? I think the only good answer here is for the case that $A$ is positive semidefinite where we can appeal to the continuous functional calculus.

Comment: I am not aware of any sensible definition in the singular case, even for 2 by 2 elements

Comment: @QiaochuYuan If the matrix $A$ is invertible then take any branch-cut running from $0$ to $\infty$ in the complex plane which avoids the spectrum of $A$ and then use e.g. holo FC of Banach algebras to define $\log(A)$ by choosing a corresponding branch of $\log$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan For instance, take $A=\left(\matrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 }\right)$.

Comment: @Yemon: sure, I'm aware that $A$ admits *a* logarithm, but that's very different from saying that *the* logarithm $\log A$ is well-defined.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I agree. But in some contexts, even knowing that you can take fractional powers of a single operator is useful, especially for operators on non-Hilbertian Banach spaces, even if it isn't nice and canonical etc

Comment: In the applied literature, usually one defines $\log A$ only for matrices having no nonpositive real eigenvalues, and takes the principal value with eigenvalues in the strip $-\pi < \Im \lambda < \pi$. For the definition, one can use the Jordan decomposition or Cauchy integral definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function#Extending_scalar_function_to_matrix_functions). Reference: Higham, Functions of matrices, beginning of Chapter 11.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni In the case that $A$ has nonpositive real eigenvalues, we can use from the folowing theorem. 
Theorem: Let $A\in GL(n,\mathbb C)$ and $\alpha \in (-1,1]$, then $\log(A^{\alpha})=\alpha \log(A)$ and if $A$ has no eigenvalues in $\mathbb R^{-}$, we have $\log(A^{-1})=- \log(A)$.
For proof, see: [Functions
of Matrices](http://bookzz.org/md5/B7C0C82FB46DB4F4979B376EA4DCA061) pag 270 theorem 11.2

Comment: @hamidkamali among the hypotheses of that theorem there is "if $A$ has no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R}^-$"  --- so it works only if $A$ has no nonpositive real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest a solution since I don't think that any of the above comments address the essentials.  Firstly, there is no need to use the logarithm to attack this problem.  One can, of course, but I think that its use just muddies the water.  There is a standard path to address this kind of problem---the Jordan canonical form (see any respectable text on linear algebra).  This allows one to reduce to the case where our matrix is a Jordan form, i.e., with identical elements in the diagonal, $1$'s in the superdiagonal and zeroes elsewhere. As pointed out by the OP there is no problem if the diagonal elements are non-zero (we remark that one can then construct the powers directly using the generalised binomial theorem. In this case the resulting infinite series is actually finite since the perturbing matrix is nilpotent).  Of course, if the Jordan bock corresponds to an eigenvalue which is not on the positive real axis, in particular if negative, then one then has the task or privilege of deciding on  a suitable choice of a branch of the power function, but one already has this problem in the one-dimensional case, i.e. when taking powers of complex numbers (at this point one would use logarithms, of course). The case where the diagonal elements are zero is a train wreck as can be seen from the simplest case where $A$ is the $2 \times 2$ Jordan matrix with zeroes in the diagonal.  This does not have a square root, i.e., a $B$ with $B^2=A$ and so things fall apart.

Comment: I agree with your last two sentences (which is what I was getting at in my own comments above)